# Send broadcast intent from PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, preferencescreen

Is it possible to directly send a broadcast intent from a PreferenceScreen?

For example, I would like to do something like the following:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="Enable">
<intent android:action="com.otherapp.ENABLE" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

But when I try this, the app FC's w/ ActivityNotFoundException.

BTW, the receiver is simply defined as:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.otherapp.ENABLE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This broadcast receiver has been tested to work ok, but just not from the PreferenceScreen.

TIA!

Comment: None... "no activity found to handle com.otherapp.ENABLE". It does work for Activity (when defined), but I'm hoping I can send a broadcast intent directly.

Comment: I think that in order for that to work, you have to define the intent in the intent-filter of the target's activity element in the manifest.

Comment: Hi, I edited the first post to show how the receiver is declared in the manifest. It's Broadcast Receiver btw, not an Activity.

Comment: Would you add the code that launchs your intent as well?

Comment: Not from the code, from the XML... The intention is to send a broadcast from the PreferenceScreen. The above XML can launch an Activity directly (no other code involved) for example, but not Broadcast Receiver. I'm hoping there's a simple way to do the same for a broadcast.

Answer (score 6):

You can extend `Preference` to make it send a broadcast when clicked:

```
public class BroadcastPreference extends Preference implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
    public BroadcastPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        getContext().sendBroadcast(getIntent());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use your custom preference in the xml file

```
<com.app.example.BroadcastPreference android:title="Enable">
    <intent android:action="com.otherapp.ENABLE" />
</com.app.example.BroadcastPreference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferences send intents to activities, not to broadcast receivers. If you want to send intents to broadcast receivers, create activity that forwards intents to broadcast receivers

```
public class ForwardingActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent incomingIntent = getIntent();
        Intent outgoingIntent = new Intent(incomingIntent);
        outgoingIntent.setComponent(null); // unblock recipients
        sendBroadcast(outgoingIntent);
    }
}
```

with no UI

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ForwardingActivity "
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.otherapp.ENABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think, you should add category `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` to `intent-filter` in your manifest.
It should look like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.otherapp.ENABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: it cannot work. activity intents are not broadcast intents, no matter the category